# how to call xxxxWithClass:(class) in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, restkit

I want to call this method in RestKit RKRoute in swift:

```
+ (instancetype)routeWithClass:(Class)objectClass pathPattern:(NSString *)pathPattern method:(RKRequestMethod)method;
```

but I find I can't use 'class' as argument label,the compiler deal it as a keyword

```
var route:RKRoute = RKRoute(class: Article.self, pathPattern: "/categories/:comment.name/articles/:articleID/comments/", method:RKRequestMethod.GET)
```

how to call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Swift documentation:

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick (`) before
>   and after it. For example, class is not a valid identifier, but
>   `class` is valid. The backticks are not considered part of the
>   identifier; `x` and x have the same meaning.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html

Thus:

```
var route:RKRoute = RKRoute(`class`: Article.self, pathPattern: "/categories/:comment.name/articles/:articleID/comments/", method:RKRequestMethod.GET)
```